# constrained nonlinear minimization with many variables

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

Here is a minimization problem I've meant to solve, but no matter what form or package I try it with, it never resolves itself.

The Problem is a **transportation problem with a quadratic objective function**. It is formulated as follows:

Minimize f(x), with f(x) being x' * C * x, subject to the equality constraints UI * x - ci = 0.

where C is a diagonal matrix of constants, UI is matrix with the values 0, 1, -1 in order to set up the constraints.

I'll provide an example that I have tried with two functions so far, `nloptr` from its likewise called package and `constrOptim`.

Here's an example for `nloptr`:

```
require(nloptr)
objective <- function(x) {return( list( "objective" = t(x) %*% C %*% x,
                                    "gradient" =  2* C %*% x )) }
constraints <- function(x) {return( list( "constraints" =   ui %*% x - ci,
                                        "jacobian" = ui))}

C <- diag(c(10,15,14,5,6,10,8))
ci <- c(20, -30, -10, -20, 40))
ui <- rbind( c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0),
             c(-1,0,0,1,0,0,0),
             c(0,-1,0,-1,1,1,0),
             c(0,0,-1,0,-1,0,1),
             c(0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1))
opts <- list("alorithm" = "NLOPT_GN_ISRES")

res <- nloptr( x0=x0, eval_f=objective, eval_g_eq = constraints, opts=opts)
```

When trying to solve this Problem with `constrOptim`, I face the problem that I have to provide starting values that are within the feasible region. However, I will ultimately have a lot of equations and don't really know how to set these starting points.

Here's the same example with `constrOptim`:

```
C <- diag(c(10,15,14,5,6,10,8))
ci <- c(20, -30, -10, -20, 40)
ui <- rbind(    c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0),
            c(-1,0,0,1,0,0,0),
            c(0,-1,0,-1,1,1,0),
            c(0,0,-1,0,-1,0,1),
            c(0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1))
start <- c(10,10,10,0,0,0,0)

objective <- function(x) { t(x) %*% C %*% x }
gradient <- function(x) { 2 * C %*% x }
constrOptim(start, objective, gradient, ui = ui, ci = ci)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
co <- coef(lm.fit(ui, ci))
co[is.na(co)] <- 0
res <- nloptr( x0=co, eval_f=objective, eval_g_eq = constraints, 
  opts=list(algorithm = "NLOPT_LD_SLSQP"))
```

giving:

```
> res

Call:
nloptr(x0 = co, eval_f = objective, eval_g_eq = constraints, 
    opts = list(algorithm = "NLOPT_LD_SLSQP"))


Minimization using NLopt version 2.4.0 

NLopt solver status: 4 ( NLOPT_XTOL_REACHED: Optimization stopped because 
xtol_rel or xtol_abs (above) was reached. )

Number of Iterations....: 22 
Termination conditions:  relative x-tolerance = 1e-04 (DEFAULT) 
Number of inequality constraints:  0 
Number of equality constraints:    5 
Optimal value of objective function:  37378.6963822218 
Optimal value of controls: 28.62408 -29.80155 21.17747 -1.375917 -17.54977 -23.6277 -16.3723
```

Comment: Thanks! It works like a charm. The results are not as I hoped them to be, but that has rather something to do with the way the problem is set up by me I'm afraid. But you approach leads to a solution, which is the first step.

Comment: Hello. I would have another question. Could it be that the solution is not a global, but only a local minimum?

Comment: I don't think so.  A local minimum of a convex function on a convex set is the global minimum.  Your function is convex as its Hessian, `2*C`, is constant and positive definitive and your constraints are convex since if `x` and `y` satisfy the constraints then `tx+(1-t)y` does too.